# Android Prevent service from being bound until async operation completes

Tags: android, service, asynchronous

I have an Android service that Activities should be able to bind to. The service starts an asynchronous operation in onCreate().

Is there any way to prevent the calling Activities from getting the onServiceConnected() callback until the asynchronous operation is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a broadcast to let your application know that the service task is done ?

Comment: This will not work. What about the clients which bind after the async task is done? They will be infinitely waiting for the broadcast.